# Is there a way to check if the game just started, or the scene just loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make some logic that tells me if the actual Unity game just loaded, or if just SceneManager just loaded scene 0. Is there a way to check this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something that should really happen only a single time when the app is started there are multiple options for this.

Among these e.g.

- Have a `static` flag and do thins only once in `Awake` if the flag is not set
- Use a dedicated setup scene that is loaded only once when the app starts, finishes your initialization and then goes to your actual fist scene and is never loaded again within that app lifecycle
- Use [`[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html) on a `static` method which is then called **once** when the first `Awake` routine has finished

---

For checking which scene was loaded you can attach a listener to [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) and check if the loaded `scene` has [`Scene.buildIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-buildIndex.html) `== 0`.

Note though that this might miss the very first scene load depending on how exactly you subscribe to the event.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can check with this unity lifecycle methods according to this link

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html

For example you can write control logic inside the awake function for this.